# How to change title of MPlayer window?

Tags: video, mplayer

Can I change title of MPlayer window? I play a video with this command:

```
mplayer pinguin.mpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mplayer -title "This is your title" (files)
```

http://mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html#VIDEO%20OUTPUT%20OPTIONS%20%28MPLAYER%20ONLY%29